# Why can't I add a property in a publish function?

Tags: meteor

I have a frustrating problem:

```
    Meteor.publish('userBox', function() {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
        if (UserBox.boxId) {
          return UserBox.find({boxId: Meteor.user()._id},
                              {'balance': 1,
                               'myGames': 1,
                               'createdGames': 1
                              });
      } else {
          UserBox.insert({boxId: Meteor.user()._id,
                          balance: 111,
                          myGames: 7,
                          createdGames: {}
                         });

          return UserBox.find({boxId: Meteor.user()._id},
                              {'balance': 1,
                               'myGames': 1,
                               'createdGames': 1
                              });
    }
  }
});
```

Why doesn't it work? I just want have another collection which will keep some object in advance to `Meteor.users` and where I can keep any additional property for current users.

Comment: in what way does it not work? Are you getting an error? or does the new object simply not show up in the collection? Please elaborate a little.

Comment: ya new object not show up in the collection. i don't get any errors. Just after restart app i don't see any information in UserBox collection, because it's still empty. even if u logged in app or not.

for example: in addition to the above code i create helpers:

http://plnkr.co/edit/joSx4eoeHekjEfRL9rm0?p=catalogue

and in template i put this cod:
http://plnkr.co/edit/DfXbwgKEOEeYcro31pu4?p=catalogue

but it doesn't work, cuz UserBox don't have any property

Comment: have you verified that manually inserting into the UserBox collection works?

Comment: yes, manually it's work via mongo comand. but what the point

Comment: Have you tried it from the meteor shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally... it was so simple... http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser

Answer (score 0):

The condition is never true, because `Meteor.user()` doesn't work in publish functions:

> Meteor.user()                 Anywhere but publish functions

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user

Use `this.userId` instead.

Comment: Did you also change anywhere you were using Meteor.user()._id?

Comment: no even this don't work, i have no idea why i cant add property in users object.
http://plnkr.co/edit/HanVlQgyG9xwfWfEznC5?p=catalogue

Comment: you are not trying to add anything to the user's object (at least not in your code above).